# Validation when displaying already existing element

Tags: python, django

When editing an already existing element in Django, I would like to show ValidationErrors for fields that are not good (because somewhere else something changed). I've tried to overload the `__init__` of the form and set `form_obj.errors['__all__']="something"` but it doesn't display any errors. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors are shown for the "data" parameter ( or instance if it's a modelform ), not "initial". You need to pass the original values as the data parameter if you want to display errors.

And then just use the usual validation methods ( raising ValidationError in clean_* methods , field specific validation, etc. ). I wouldn't mess up with the error dictionary, it's an internal API.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do custom form validation, you can implement the `clean_<fieldname>()` or `clean()` method on your form, and raise a `ValidationError` for each error. See the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/) for details